# How do I combine these regular expressions to match the variations in this text?

Tags: python, regex

I have data of this format:

```
Charter by <company> from <origin> to <destination>
```

where any or all of the `by <company>`, `from <origin>`, or `to <destination>` blocks could be missing. I'm trying to write a regular expression that will a) match the company, origin, and destination, and b) account for the fact that, e.g., the company name might be missing, in which case it should be blank.

One option is to write a separate regular expression for every possible combination of blocks, like so:

```
import re

def parse_line(line):
    pattern = "^Charter by ([\S ]+) from ([\S ]+) to ([\S ]+)$"
    match = re.match(pattern, line)
    if match is not None:
        company, origin, destination = match.groups()
        return((company, origin, destination))

    pattern = "^Charter by ([\S ]+) from ([\S ]+)$"
    match = re.match(pattern, line)
    if match is not None:
        company, origin = match.groups()
        destination = ""
        return((company, origin, destination))

    # other pattern combinations
    # etc...


def main():
    data = """Charter by Maersk from China to England
Charter from France
Charter by Safmarine to Poland
Charter by Safmarine from Los Angeles
Charter
Charter to New York
"""

    for line in data.splitlines():
        result = parse_line(line)
        if result is not None:
            company, origin, destination = parse_line(line)
            print("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(company, origin, destination))

main()
```

This is annoying but doable for this simple, **contrived** example data, but my actual data are much more complex: each line could have up to ten "blocks" like this, so manually specifying each of the 2^10 possible combinations isn't feasible.

I thought this pattern would work:

```
pattern = "^Charter( by ([\S ]+))?( from ([\S ]+))?( to ([\S ]+))?$"
match = re.split(pattern, line)
```

because it allows each of the blocks to be optional, but as an example, for the line `Charter by Maersk from China to England`, the split returns

```
['', ' by Maersk from China to England', 'Maersk from China to England', None, None, None, None, '']
```

Clearly, the problem is that the first `[\S ]+` is matching all the way to end of the string, instead of stopping at the `from` (note the leading space), but I'm not sure how to handle this, since company names, origins, and destinations could all include spaces. Once I get the pattern hammered out, [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) should make pulling the pieces out much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a **non-greedy** pattern form :

```
pattern = "^Charter( by ([\S ]+?))?( from ([\S ]+?))?( to ([\S ]+?))?$"
```

On your example, this gives :

```
['', ' by Maersk', 'Maersk', ' from China', 'China', ' to England', 'England', '']
```

Comment: Thank you; combining this with named groups like so `pattern = "^Charter( by (?P<company>[\S ]+?))?( from (?P<origin>[\S ]+?))?( to (?P<destination>[\S ]+?))?$"` looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `by` is always coming before `from` if exists and `from` is coming before `to` if exists, let's use 3 regular expressions to capture the by, from and to values relying on what comes after each of the blocks. For instance, when capturing the `by` value, we are extracting everything between `by` and "from" or "to" or end of the string.

The code:

```
import re

data = """Charter by Maersk from China to England
Charter from France
Charter by Safmarine to Poland
Charter by Safmarine from Los Angeles
Charter
Charter to New York
"""

company_pattern = re.compile(r"by (.*?)(?:from|to|$)")
origin_pattern = re.compile(r"from (.*?)(?:to|$)")
destination_pattern = re.compile(r"to (.*?)$")
for line in data.splitlines():
    match = company_pattern.search(line)
    company = match.group(1).strip() if match else ""

    match = origin_pattern.search(line)
    origin = match.group(1).strip() if match else ""

    match = destination_pattern.search(line)
    destination = match.group(1).strip() if match else ""

    print([company, origin, destination])
```

Prints:

```
['Maersk', 'China', 'England']
['', 'France', '']
['Safmarine', '', 'Poland']
['Safmarine', 'Los Angeles', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', 'New York']
```

Note that `(?:...)` indicates a *non-capturing group*, `.*?` is a *non-greedy* match for any characters any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need might be:

```regex
^Charter(?: by ([\S ]+?))?(?: from ([\S ]+?))?(?: to ([\S ]+?))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gqWRJGWDY4s7cPYv)

Notes:

1. `(...)` is capturing group, ie. group that you can access for example via `.groups()`, `(?:...)` is non capturing one, not shown in `.groups()`.
2. `[\S ]+` is greedy – it matches as much as possible. `[\S ]+?` is lazy – matches the shortest text possible.
3. `(...)?` or `(?:...)?` group is optional – it may or may not be present in text.

`re.split` is wrong tool: use `re.match` (or `re.search`), like:

```
   import re
   pattern = r'^Charter(?: by ([\S ]+?))?(?: from ([\S ]+?))?(?: to ([\S ]+?))?$'

   match = re.match(pattern, 'Charter by Maersk from China to England')
   match.groups()
=> ('Maersk', 'China', 'England')

   match = re.match(pattern, 'Charter')
   match.groups()
=> (None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with three regular expressions, `re.findall` and an assistant function:

```
def joiner(x):
    if x: return ''.join(x[0])
    else: return ''

patterns = [re.compile(r'by ([A-Za-z]+)(\s[A-Z][a-z]*)?'),
            re.compile(r'to ([A-Za-z]+)(\s[A-Z][a-z]*)?'),
            re.compile(r'from ([A-Za-z]+)(\s[A-Z][a-z]*)?')]

results = [[joiner(re.findall(p, line)) for line in data.splitlines()] for p in patterns]
```

Output:

```
[['Maersk', '', 'Safmarine', 'Safmarine', '', ''],
 ['China', 'France', '', 'Los Angeles', '', ''],
 ['England', '', 'Poland', '', '', 'New York']]
```

Speed is not that bad:

```
In [175]: %timeit [[joiner(re.findall(p, line)) for line in data.splitlines()] for p in patterns]
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.8 µs per loop
```

Would be faster/simpler if it weren't for city names like "New York" and "Los Angeles"

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately, the data aren't contrived, so spaces in location names are unavoidable.

Answer (score -3):

I guess I got it please tell me if it is helping you:

`regexp = "^by(.*)from(.*)to(.*)$"`

`.` mean everycharacter
`*` mean 0 or mutltiple time

Comment: It does not help. Question clearly states that `by ...`, `from ...` and `to ...` may be missing.